# Ruby coinflip simulation (head or number)

Tags: ruby

Hey guys i need to do a program that simulates a coinflip and give out head or number.I did that

```
a = rand(1..2)
if a == 1 then
  puts "HEAD!"
else
  puts "NUMBER!"
end

enter = gets
if enter == "\n"
  a = rand(1..2)
  if a == 1 then
    puts "HEAD!"
  else
    puts "NUMBER!"
  end
end
```

but how can i include everytime you press enter it should continue and continue simulating coinflip like ... HEAD (enter) HEAD (enter) NUMBER (enter) and so on.

Comment: You probably need a loop. Side note: You could do `['HEAD','NUMBER'].sample` for the flip.

Comment: Please indent your code properly and when doing so use two-spaces:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of *loop*, not just an `if`. Here's a short way to do it:

```
loop do
  puts ['HEAD', 'NUMBER'].sample
  break if gets != "\n"
end
```

Or if you're ok with stopping by pressing CTRL-C:

```
loop do
  puts ['HEAD', 'NUMBER'].sample
  gets
end
```

Using a post-loop test (i.e., do the `gets` and possibly `break` *after* printing the flip result) is more appropriate here, as it avoids the code duplication. Also see this popular Ruby style guide:
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#loop-with-break
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#infinite-loop

Comment: thank you but how can i add in the end the percentage share of the coinflips?Like when i press 5 times enter and get 5 times HEAD the programe should say you throw 5 out of 5 coinflips 5 times Heads ---> 100%

Comment: Or `print ["HEAD", "COIN"].sample while gets`

Comment: @steenslag I considered that, but it doesn't print anything before hitting the first enter.

Comment: @ÜäöQwer For that I'd put each value into a variable and then `puts` that. And use two variables to keep track of the counts, using the value in the variable to determine what count to increase. If you need more help with this, please make that a new question.

Comment: @ÜäöQwer Or... you could use`if p(['HEAD', 'NUMBER'].sample) == 'HEAD'`, though that's already a bit large. Or `rand(2)` could be used in at least two nice ways.

Comment: Stefan im confused, im new and i dont know how you mean that. Could you give me another hints?Are you german?If you are german you can tell it in german i will understand it.